# Scrapy: selecting dynamically-loaded content with "More" button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape content from page similar to this: `https://www.newsweek.pl/nwpl_2018002_20181231`. It has "More" (pl. *Więcej*) button at the bottom of the page, which dynamically loads next articles. Preferably I would like to use Scrapy to do the task, because my other spiders use it, but first I need all of the articles urls; so I'm trying to `click()` this button with Selenium as follow:

```
def parse_issue(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Parse function called parse_issue on {}'.format(response.url))
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True:
            try:
                more_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="showMoreBtn"]')
                time.sleep(2)
                more_button.click()
                time.sleep(5)
                print('clicked.')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break
        articles_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-md-1-4 smallItem"]/a')
        articles_url = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in articles_elements]
        print(articles_url, response.url)
```

Unfortunately, as a result I only get urls of articles that are already in the source of the page. Can someone suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the logic.While running infinte loop and loading for the page to get element values.

1. Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() to click on the button.
2. Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() to get all elements.
3. Declare a `list` before `while loop` and while clicking on `More button` keep checking if item **exists** already inside the list else **append** into list.

**Code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.newsweek.pl/nwpl_2018002_20181231")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.cmp-button_button.cmp-intro_acceptAll"))).click()
articles_url=[]
while True:

    try:
        articles_elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.elemRelative")))
        for element in articles_elements:
            if element.get_attribute("href") in articles_url:
                continue
            else:
                articles_url.append(element.get_attribute("href"))
        #Click Show More Button
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='showMoreBtn']"))).click()
        time.sleep(2)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

print(articles_url)
print(len(articles_url))
```

**Output on Console:**

```
['https://www.newsweek.pl/dariusz-cwiklak-kosciol-i-rzad-szczuja-seksem-felieton/8cljc0t', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/tomasz-lis-kosciol-i-panstwo-pis-felieton/jj6jnh1', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/marcin-marczak-testuje-samochody/qbv7f1m', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/biznes/marcin-marczak-testuje-samochody/q7g4gn2', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/notowania-rafal-bohenek-i-martyna-wojciechowska/61b04bd', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/krzysztof-materna-rzad-i-kosciol-drza-przed-seksem-felieton/59s9cvz', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wydarzenie-tygodnia-zamachy-terrorystyczne-w-nowej-zelandii/bjy6wjz', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/henryk-sawka-episkopat-i-pedofilia-rysunek/rft1lz7', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kartka-z-kalendarza-slowo-ok-debiutuje-w-prasie/gge77hw', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/z-bliska-wydra-olbrzymia-i-czapla-czarnobrzucha-zobacz-zdjecie/xqpy3hj', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/zbigniew-holdys-sedziowie-przysiegli-i-glosne-zbrodnie-felieton/z7tjc4x', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/marcin-meller-walka-ze-strachem-przed-homopropaganda-felieton/63t1d5m', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/biznes/gadzety-sluchawki-do-ucha-bez-kabli-nowe-technologie/91kjww0', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/gadzety-sluchawki-do-ucha-bez-kabli-nowe-technologie/lybxzqr', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/pis-straszy-osobami-lgbt-tak-partia-chce-wygrac-wybory/1ksj5s9', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/agata-bielik-robson-o-tym-dlaczego-prawica-boi-sie-seksu-wywiad/n30lmzt', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/polskie-nastolatki-i-seks-jak-strasza-nim-dorosli/mdey5s5', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/jacek-saryusz-wolski-sylwetka-polityka-i-znawcy-ue/lkkt1ed', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/madeleine-albright-o-przyszlosci-usa-i-trumpie-wywiad/66bffm3', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/polska/spoleczenstwo/slawomir-swierzynski-polityczne-ambicje-lidera-bayer-full/0nmhzme', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/psychologia/psychologia-zlosc-jak-opowiadac-o-niej-dzieciom/r4k75fb', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/polska/spoleczenstwo/uprzedzenia-polakow-zalezne-od-pogladow-politycznych/v2724h3', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/psychologia/psychologia-agnieszka-stein-jak-rozmawiac-z-dziecmi-o-seksie/jkt2yj6', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/psychologia/michal-czernecki-o-zaufaniu-relacjach-i-swojej-ksiazce-wywiad/r711jgv', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/historia/harry-kessler-sylwetka-niemieckiego-zolnierza-i-dyplomaty/j4h7yl7', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/psychologia/psychologia-po-co-nam-wstyd-emocje-ochronne/5zjh7lg', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/swiat/real-madryt-tajemnice-najslynniejszego-klubu-pilkarskiego/0p9mz56', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/swiat/brexit-rozbije-jednosc-ue-tego-chcieliby-putin-i-murdoch/5b6pem5', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/swiat/bernie-sanders-pierwszy-socjalista-ameryki-i-kandydat-na-prezydenta/7th7vd1', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/nauka/wyscig-plemnikow-jak-rajd-paryz-dakar-nowe-odkrycia-naukowcow/s0s996b', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/biznes/zakaz-handlu-w-niedziele-polacy-maja-dosc-czy-rzad-zniesie-zakaz/zyl36b1', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/zakaz-handlu-w-niedziele-polacy-maja-dosc-czy-rzad-zniesie-zakaz/yz7dzzm', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/gospodarka-i-obietnice-wyborcze-pis-kto-za-to-wszystko-zaplaci/r87v3kn', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/biznes/gospodarka-i-obietnice-wyborcze-pis-kto-za-to-wszystko-zaplaci/8xrz977', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/magdalena-i-borys-lankoszowie-o-filmie-ciemno-prawie-noc-wywiad/fjqj597', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/japonia-i-rodzina-w-filmie-zlodziejaszki-hirokazu-koreedy/r7kmsyn', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/nauka/najstarsze-tatuaze-swiata-wielka-moc-kaktusowej-igly/pvppbzw', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/serhij-zadan-o-konformizmie-w-nowej-powiesci-recenzja/ntgrnc3', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/ellen-page-o-nowej-roli-w-serialu-hollywood-i-sytuacji-osob-lgbt/sp9zy0n', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/love-death-robots-nowy-serial-netflixa-o-przyszlosci/54bjyv6', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/grzyby-i-ludzie-czyli-nasladowanie-natury-recenzja-wystawy/v2bnhyv', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/powrot-the-cinematic-orchestra-na-bardzo-udanej-plycie-recenzja/c0pbept', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/ola-bilinska-i-konrad-kucz-razem-na-nowej-plycie-recenzja/7efdxdn', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/american-dream-po-polsku-w-ksiazce-doroty-malesy-recenzja/bv2d8lb', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/spektakl-nogi-syreny-to-znakomity-kabaret-recenzja/p002s9b', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/kultura/starosc-tez-radosc-recenzja-ksiazki-nasze-dusze-noca/sj0de13', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/wiedza/psychologia/psychologia-milosc-zlapana-w-pulapke-jak-dawac-przyklad/mq55r7p', 'https://www.newsweek.pl/opinie/tomasz-lis-kosciol-i-panstwo-pis-felieton/wgbkt0m']
48
```

Comment: Hi, basically your approach worked, but only for the first page (my output is the same as yours). For all the following I get this exception: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: The website you have provided for an example it has only 48 elements after clicking twice on the more button.if you have other url to investigate then post that url and also how many links you are after?

Comment: Ok. I wrapped first `WebDriverWait()` into `try:`-`except:` and it seems to be working properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On click of more button, website is making a request which you could track by inspecting network in your browser's console. You need to write `rule` which will extract all links from the pagination and callback of this `rule` will be to `parse`